# Public function which creates an automated string output based on a cell value. VBA

Tags: excel, vba, reporting

I'm trying to create a vba function with a string output based on a percentage cell reference that will read "Increase by __" if positive or "Decrease by __" if negative and "No change" if zero.

Any help would be great!

Comment: This community expects an effort from the originator. You have to post the VBA code you have worked and issues you are facing with it. This can also be achieved with formula.

Answer (score 0):

I normally wouldn't as someone has already said, you should be showing any efforts of what you have tried but since it's such a simple function then it's no time wasted.

Please ensure you read and understand what it does so you can learn and be able to do this sort of thing in the future. SO isn't a free code writing website.

To use this. Open Visual Basic and go Import -> Module. Don't put this in a sheet module. Then you can use it in your sheet as `=PercentChange(A1)` for example. You can change the name of the function to whatever you want but make sure to change all of the `PercentChange` to the new name otherwise it won't work.

The code:

```
Public Function PercentChange(rng As Range)

If rng.Value = 0 Then
    PercentChange = "No Change"
ElseIf rng.Value < 0 Then
    PercentChange = "Decreased by " & Format(Abs(rng.Value), "0%") 'For Decimals do "0.00%" etc
ElseIf rng.Value > 0 Then
    PercentChange = "Increased by " & Format(rng.Value, "0%")
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Please note this is only basic and will only work on a single selected cell.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom cell format, no need for VBA:

Format Cells: Custom: Type:

```
"Increase by" 0.00%;"Decrease by "0.00%; "No change"
```